# Setting Postgresql schema with hibernate parameters

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a multi-tenant application using schemas to separate tenants. My connection pool does not support multi-tenant out-of-the-box (Dropwizard) - so I am trying to set the tenant's schema manually on retrieval. However, I am getting an SQL syntax error.

### Code:

```
NativeQuery fpq = this.getSessionFactory()
                          .getCurrentSession()
                          .createNativeQuery("SET schema=?");
fpq.setParameter(1, tenantSchema);
fpq.executeUpdate();
```

### Error:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL: SET schema=?
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [myapplication_client1]
WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 12
```

I've also tried `"SET search_path=?"` and `"SET search_path TO ?"` with the same result. This seems pretty straight forward, what am I doing wrong? The `tenantSchema` variable is generated using an untrustworthy string, so it is important to build the parameters correctly and not manually concat the SQL.

Update: Stepping through the debugger, I have verified Hibernate is correctly converting the statement to `SET schema 'myapplication_client1'` - but it still fails, I don't know why. It definitely has something to do with `setParameter` since the query runs fine if I hard-code it.

Comment: you should be able to modify your sql to include the `schema` e.g. `select colA from myschema.mytable;`

Comment: @ScaryWombat unfortunately that is not an option. The tenant setting logic has to be in a single class. It is important every query only operates within its own tenant and relying on every statement to manually set the schema opens up too large a risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an identifier as a parameter in a prepared statement. The schema name is an identifier just like a table name and you can't do `select * from ?` either.

You have to concatenate the parameter to your query:

```
NativeQuery fpq = this.getSessionFactory()
                          .getCurrentSession()
                          .createNativeQuery("SET schema=" + tenantSchema);
fpq.executeUpdate();
```

As this is a parameter from an "untrusted" source, you will need to verify that it's correct before doing that. A simple way would be to retrieve all schemas using `DatabaseMetaData.getSchemas()` and validate that the parameter is one of them.

---

Unrelated:

> Hibernate is correctly converting the statement to `SET schema 'myapplication_client1'`

No, Hibernate is not converting anything. This is just the way the Postgres JDBC driver implements the `PreparedStatement.toString()` method. It does not mean it's the query sent to the database. The `toString()` method is only there for debugging purposes as a convenience (e.g. for logging purposes)